# How can we calculate this line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, line-integrals

I am currently working on the problem given below. I tried to solve it, but I can't find a proper solution. [image]

We need to calculate the given integral of the function f(x,y,z) from pi to 2.5pi, along the given curve and path r(t). This is what I have. I interpreted cos(t), sin(t), t as x,y,z repectively.
I would appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: You should use mathjax to type in your question and your work instead of posting an image. Images cannot be searched. I know it may sound a lot of work to type in but more you use mathjax, easier it becomes. I have seen people get downvoted for posting images instead of typing in. So if you want your question to be received well, it is in your interest to type in.

Comment: Here is a basic mathjax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: calculate the integral for each term of the sum separately. Integration by party might help.

Comment: integral of $t e^{-t}$ is $-(1+t) e^{-t} + c$ by integration by parts as mentioned by mag. Similarly integrate other terms

Comment: I second Math Lover's suggestion. Using a photo might be [convenient for you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34226) but it is bad for the site. Please [do not use image for texts or math expressions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) that is **essential to the question**.